# Quick! Where can I upload a file so a simple-minded printer can download it later, or convert a pdf / MS Word into a high quality image file?

Tags: pdf, conversion, upload

This is an embarrassingly dumb question, but it's getting urgent:

I had time to kill at the office, so I designed a nice Valentine's Day card for my wife.  Now I just need to print it out.  It's in MS Word and .pdf format.

I don't have a suitable printer at work, but that's not problem.  I can just pop into a convenience store on the way home and use one of their all-singing, all-dancing, scanner / printers.  They're *everywhere* here in Japan.

But ... ooops ... no removable media to hand.  "No problem," I thought.  "I can just upload it somewhere, and the super-duper-mega photocopier will download and print it out for me.  All I have to do is make a note of the URL."

But, here's the snag.  Where can I upload it to?  I've tried all the obvious places, and a few non-obvious places, but none of will just give me a direct URL.  There are always some hoops to jump through, or buttons to click, or they insist on presenting the .pdf file within some kind of fancy frame. I doubt the printer at a convenience store could cope with that.

Alternatively, maybe someone could recommend an on-line service that will convert the document to a **high-quality** image file?

I'd like an answer in about ... um ... 25 minutes.

Comment: I should have searched before posting my whole question.  It turns out that others have answered this question before.  My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) needs a registration but gives a nice simple directly downloadable file in the public folder

Comment: I already had a dropbox account, but didn't know they offered that service, so that's the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use some photo printing service with online service? They have so called "express" processing so you simply upload it using their website and after some time can pick it up in their store. I used Fujifilm local service here, but I think they must have something similar also in Japan. The same probably with Kodak and others.

However, you will have to convert the PDF to some image format to be able to process it as photo. You can use PDF Creator and "print" the doc or pdf to jpg, or the portable PDF-Xchange Viewer to export the PDF as image.

I already used this approach and the result looked pretty good on the glossy photo paper. :-)

Comment: That's a splendid idea.  I'll probably do that next year.  :-)